# Keep carriage returns on pasting string from Excel cell to Outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to paste a single cell to Outlook keeping the carriage returns. I can't use `RangeToHTML` because it pastes as a table and I need it to be plain text so I've tried this:

```
For Each C In wsEnv.Range("A1:A17")
    If C.Row = 1 Then
        wsEnv.Cells(19, 1) = C & vbCrLf
    ElseIf C.Row < 17 Then
        wsEnv.Cells(19, 1) = wsEnv.Cells(19, 1) & C & vbCrLf
    Else
        wsEnv.Cells(19, 1) = wsEnv.Cells(19, 1) & C
    End If
Next C

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = Para
    .CC = CC
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Asunto
    .HTMLBody = wsEnv.Cells(19, 1)
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

The result is this:
[image: Result]

Is there any way to keep the format on the cell or use the `RangeToHTML` function to paste as text and not a table?

Comment: You are using a HTML mail `.HTMLBody` and carriage returns have no effect in HTML code. Either use a text only mail or replace all `vbCrLf` with the HTML code for a linebreak `<br>`. • Actually `.HTMLBody`  is waiting for HTML code not for plain text.

Comment: Damn! You are so correct, post it as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks @Pᴇʜ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a HTML mail `.HTMLBody` and carriage returns have no effect in HTML code. Actually `.HTMLBody` is waiting for HTML code not for plain text.

- Either use a "text only" mail:

  Set the [MailItem.BodyFormat property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat) to `olFormatPlain` (see [OlBodyFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbodyformat)) and use `.Body` instead of `.HTMLBody`

  ```
  .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
  .Body = wsEnv.Cells(19, 1).Value
  ```
- or [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) all `vbCrLf` with the HTML code for a linebreak `<br>`.

  ```
  .HTMLBody = Replace$(wsEnv.Cells(19, 1).Value, vbCrLf, "<br>")
  ```

Note that the linebreaks you enter in cells using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> are `vbLf` not `vbCrLf`!